# Error, linked lists using C programming

Tags: c, linked-list, push, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to code simple push function and everything is fine until run time, executed code crashes. Anyone can clarify the reason, please ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list{
int order;
struct list *next;

}list;

void push(struct list **arg,int i);

int main()
   {
struct list **ptr=NULL;

for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    push(ptr,i);
  }

return 0;
     }

void push(struct list **arg,int i){

 struct list *temp;
 temp= malloc(sizeof(list));

temp->order=i;

temp->next=*arg;

*arg=temp;

}
```

Comment: `struct list **ptr=NULL;` needs to be `struct list *ptr=NULL` and `push(ptr,i);` then becomes `push(&ptr,i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
list *ptr=NULL;
     ^^^           
for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
    push( &ptr,i);
         ^^^^
  }
```

Otherwise if to declare like this

```
struct list **ptr=NULL;
```

then this dereferencing

```
*ptr
```

results in undefined behavior.

Comment: But when I pass it to another function like print function it works fine, can you clarify the reason sir ?

Comment: void print_list(list ** head) {


    while ((*head) != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", (*head)->order); // works fine !
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }
}

Comment: @YasserMohamed I do not know how you add now new elements and how the function is called. You can ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434299/c-programming-error-printing-linked-list-at-run-time-executed-code-crashes